# WindowBuilder GUI, where to create the main method and objects?

Tags: java, user-interface, windowbuilder

so I'm creating my first GUI ever and I'm a little lost when it comes to where to declare each thing. I created a class like `public class GUI extends JFrame` where I developed the "visual part" with WindowBuilder (I'm using eclipse).

Until now, I used to have a class named `Client` where I created all the objects and executed the functions. But now, I don't know how to manage it with the GUI. Should I delete the `Client` class and put everything in the `GUI` class or should I call the methods of the user interface from the client?

There are millions of ways of doing this but, I'd be nice if someone could explain me a little bit how to decide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I use WindowBuilder I keep the generated GUI and my business logic in separated classes. I generate the handler methods for the different GUI events and from those ones I call my business logic defined in my own classes.

The WindowBuilder is not only generating but also parsing its generated GUI code. I try to make minimal code change in that class to avoid conflicts with WindowBuilder.

I would create the main method in a different class and use the generated frame from that one.

Comment: So it's the GUI which calls the methods? Then in the GUI Class I should have the objects, shouldn't I?